# malloc problem when writing on a file

Tags: c, malloc, printf

A garbage data appears whenever i write the data in the text file... Why is it like that?
Here's my code... Thanks

```
int main(void)
{
   unsigned int option = 0;
   int i = 0;
   }
   getch();
   while(option != 5){
      option = display(); 
      switch(option){
          case 5: save();
                  break;        
      }
       for(i = 0; i < recordCtr; i++){
         free(array[i]);}  
   } 
}  

save(){
     FILE *stream = NULL;
     stream = fopen("student.txt", "wt");
     printf("\nSaving the student list directory. Wait a moment please...");
             int i =0;
                 for (i=0; i<3; i++){
                    fprintf(stream, "%5s %30s %5s\n", array[i]->studentID, array[i]->name, array[i]->course);
                 }
     fclose(stream);                     
}
```

Comment: You need to post the smallest possible code that demonstrates the problem. You posted several pages.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to a particular situation. Then debug it.

Comment: As a general rule, if you're copy-and-pasting chunks of code often, it is usually a sign that you're doing it wrong. Consider writing more functions or using a loop to read in or print your student data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bugs.

1. recordCtr is always incremented. If I chose to add 2 times then you fill array[0], array[1] and array[2]. But when you are freeing memory, you are freeing up to recordCtr value. In this case you happen to free up to 6 student records. It could be disaster.
2. As soon as the switch ends you are freeing student records memory. If user choose to exit then save() is caled which tries to save student records which are freed already. Its bad idea to read from freed memory.

When do you see garbage data. I mean under what Input?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You never allocate memory for `struct student *array[MAX];`</strike>

I think this is overwriting your data maybe?

`strcpy(array[0]->studentID, dummy);`

studentID is a char[5] and dummy is a char[30]. It's been a while since using C for m, but you could be smashing your other data.

Comment: The array of pointers is correctly allocated with static duration, and as far as I can tell, he only uses pointers in the array that are properly malloced.